# How is AbstractTestCase linked to UiTestBase<D> in QAF 2.18 version?

Tags: qaf

I am new to QAF 2.18 & trying to understand how an `AbstractTestCase` is able to accept a type parameter using Generic's in below case.

```
public abstract class AbstractTestCase<D, B extends UiTestBase<D>>
```

The `WebDriverTestCase` extends `AbstractTestCase<D, B extends UiTestBase<D>>` that said, the `AbstractTestCase` must and should make a use of Interface `UiTestBase` or the classes that have the implementation of the interface `UiTestBase<D>`. I tried to drill down more & couldn't find that `QAFExtendedWebDriver` and `WebDriverTestBase` classes don't implement `UiTestBase` in any way. Could anyone help me understand how is this working? Thanks in advance.

```
public class WebDriverTestCase extends AbstractTestCase<QAFExtendedWebDriver, WebDriverTestBase>
```